# stop touch from passing to lower surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a `SurfaceView` "over" a `GLSurfaceView` in Android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
> 

<my.project.ActionSurface
    android:id="@+id/actionSurface"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" 
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
/>

<fi.harism.curl.CurlView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/larryMoeCurly"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

(Many thanks to [harism](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680519/harism) for his [page curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) code!)

In my ActionSurface, I have this to detect touches:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        newX = (int) event.getX();
        newY = (int) event.getY();
        diffX = newX - x;
        diffY = newY - y;
        Log.d(TAG, "touched at x:" + newX + " y:" + newY);
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I touch my ActionSurface, it responds correctly, but the touch goes through to the CurlView as well.  How do I stop the touch from "passing through" to the other surface?

Comment: Note that Views are rendered in the order they appear in your xml file, so actually the ActionSurface is rendered "under" the CurlView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could add an OnTouchListener to your surface view, and catch the event there (return true):

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```